# Iterating through STL classes in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator

Lets say we have std::map and we want to iterate through. What are advantages/disadvantages ( or what is the main difference ) between this two iterations?

```
map<string,int> m0 { { "name1", 20 }, { "name2", 30 }, { "name3", 40 } };
for( auto &it : m0 )
    it = m0 . erase( it );
```

and

```
for (auto it=m0.begin(); it!=m0.end(); ) 
    it = m0.erase(it);
```

The first code isn't compalible and I don't know why although in cppreference syntax is like the first one.

Comment: `for( auto &it : m0 )` -- Even though you named the variable 'it', it's not actually an iterator, but a reference to the element of the map.

Comment: The first one doesn't give you an iterator in the loop it gives you an element reference. You can't delete using it.

Comment: What's wrong with `m0.clear();`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using a range based for loop evaluates the end condition only once. A classical loop with iterators evaluates it on each iteration.
A range based loop always iterates the entire container. A classical loop with iterators can iterate only parts of the container.
The ranged loop syntax is more terse and clear.

Those are the main differences as I see them.

Comment: Also one uses iterators where the other gives you the element directly.

Comment: Currious as to the downvote(s). What exactly is wrong with my answer?